# Unable to implement debouncing in function which has parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement **debouncing** in an API function which is called every time when user type something in an autocomplete box. But somehow when ever i'm typing something it is calling main API function instead of debounce function. Below is the code:

```
$scope.searchTextChange = function(searchText){
debounceSearch(getAllIds(searchText),1000); //getAllIds get called everytime upon keyboard input
}

const debounceSearch= (callback, delay) => {
  let timeout = null;
  return (...args) => {
    const next = () => 
    callback(...args);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(next, delay);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling it while you are initiating `debounceSearch` in this code block, you are effectively calling `getAllIds`.

```
$scope.searchTextChange = function(searchText){
  debounceSearch(getAllIds(searchText),1000); 
}
```

A better way to go would be to make the scope `searchTextChange` to be debounced, like:

```
$scope.searchTextChange = debounceSearch( function(searchText) {
  getAllIds(searchText); 
}, 1000);
```

Which would solve your problem all together and make it clear from reading the code that the `searchTextChange` is debounced (with a warning that if you have some calls to the `this` context, you should bind the callback to this or use an arrow function)

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('searchInput');
const result = document.getElementById('results');

// taken from: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

elem.addEventListener('keypress', debounce( search, 1000 ) );

function search( e ) {
  results.innerText += 'You\'ve searched for ' + e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that debounceSearch is not a function after your suggested change.

Comment: Well, it's your code file @Vin, you suggested the name of `debounceSearch`. Is the name `debounceSearch` in scope from where you are calling it?

Comment: If i'm doing your suggested change it is giving an error and yes it is in scope.

Comment: I have resolved the error but now it is not executing getAllIds function any suggestion ? I think it is not executing because when i'm typing $scope.searchTextChange 
 should be called every time on key press which is not happening right now.

Comment: @Vin, I added an example how you can use it, and I also added the `debounce` functionality as it is in `underscore.js`, but taken from a blog when quickly searching for it

Comment: In my scenario i have to pass the value(text) to `getAllIds(searchText)` which is captured by `$scope.searchTextChange(searchText)` function, so when ever user type something it should get called. In the above example `e.target.value` will provide us the value but in my case it won't work.

This is the flow which i'm trying to implement:
User Presses the key -> `$scope.searchTextChange(searchText)` will capture the 
text -> after that `debounceSearch` function should execute which will then call `getAllIds(searchText)`.

Comment: @Vin Did you try using the version of `debounce` I suggested?

Comment: @Vin, did you validate what you receive inside `searchText` inside the `getAllIds` method? Where does `searchText` originate from, these are all not in your original question

Comment: `$scope.searchTextChange` triggered from frontend which is associated with an autocomplete(search box). and then passed to `getAlllIds(searchText)` API function to get the result from database.

Comment: You are not really answering my questions, did you debug or log any of the values you intend to receive there?

Comment: In `searchText` string is coming which is supplied by the user for ex:- 'National'

Comment: So, in other words, you didn't debug or validate any of that? So you don't really know what you are sending into `getAllIds`. At least, that's my take on the answers you are supplying

Comment: If you look in to my code above `searchText` is a parameter which is again passed to `getAllIds` which is a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216427/discussion-between-icepickle-and-vin).